# Group by non-scalar value

Tags: sql

Given a one-to-many relationship between `Person` and `Item`

```
 Person           Item
 -------          ------
 Id   <-----.     Id
 Name       `---- PersonId
                  Label
```

Where there are may people and `Item.Label` takes few distinct values, it might make sense to adopt an equivalent schema:

```
Person        List      Item
--------      ------    ------
Id       .--> Id <--.   Id
ListId --`          `-- ListId
Name                    Label
```

That way many people can share the same list.

The migration from second schema to the first is trivial. My question is, **how to migrate from the first schema to the second**?

The challenge is to pick exactly one representative `Person` for each possible outcome of

```
SELECT Label FROM Item WHERE PersonId = ?
```

I was able to solve the problem by using `FOR XML` present in MS SQL server. That is,

```
SELECT P.Id, (SELECT Label FROM Item WHERE PersonId = P.Id FOR XML) list
FROM Person P
```

and then simply `SELECT MIN(P.Id) FROM ... GROUP BY list` to collect representatives. I'm unsatisfied with this workaround though and wish to find a more pure solution.

**edit:**

```
SELECT p.Id, q.Id FROM Person p, Person q
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( --symmetric difference between
    (SELECT Label FROM Item WHERE PersonId = p.Id) --and 
    (SELECT Label FROM Item WHERE PersonId = q.id))
```

Should be the equivalence relation of Persons, for which representatives need to be found. I still wouldn't know how to finish, and this does seem rather inefficient.

Comment: From the looks of this, an Item can only be in one list? It might make more sense for List to contain a PersonID, and a ItemID.  Then you can  query the List table for all Items a particular Person may have, or all Persons who have a particular Item.

Comment: @aglassman, there may be multiple Items with the same labels in different lists, but no two lists can have exactly same set of items.

Comment: Please indicate your DBMS (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc.)

Comment: I strongly encourage you to stop using plain `ID` as a column name. Call it `WhateverID` everywhere, including its own table. Some day you will think back on this advice and feel regretful for not implementing it or grateful that you did. :)

Comment: @ErikE, why in the world would DBMS matter here? I already have a DBMS specific solutioin. Now I'm looking for one that isn't.

Comment: It's just nice to know so that if someone does provide you with that non-database-specific table design advice, and also wants to give you some SQL script, he can do it in the one you need.

Comment: @ErikE, that's the thing. I needed it a long time ago and I got around it. I don't need it any more, I only want to learn a better way.

Answer (score 0):

It depends! I suggest you to stick your model to your business logic.
If people own pre-mades sets of items it makes senses to create a table to hold that logic.

Consider people can own just "home edition", "pro edition" or "std edition".
It makes sense to create a relational table between Edition_Items that way that edition can contain items (A,B),(A,B,C,D) and (A,C) for example.

And you can make a relational table between People and Edition it owns. At your scenario if that editions are "customized" editions, even if you got two to contain the same set of items you can consider they are different sets (just because they are owned by different people).

So that "Assembled Set" table can be used as a relational table between people and items.

**Edit:**

OP comment enforces my last statement.
So your "List" table can be a relational table between People and items.

```
|People |  |List| |List_Item|  |Item|
|-------|  |----| |---------|  |----|
|P1, L1 |  | L1 | | L1, I1  |  |I1  |
|P2, L2 |  | L2 | | L1, I2  |  |I2  |
           | L3 | | L2, I1  |  |I3  |
           | L4 | | L2, I1  |
```

Seeing it you can ask, why keep a List table? That's use full if that List got some properties like: isDeleted, Description, CreateTime, etc

And the final question is? We put a reference of list on people or a reference of people in the list (or create another relational table?)

It depenses on:
1) People List is a 1-1 relation?
2) Who comes first? (egg and chicken problem?)
That's usually better questioning: Who can exist without the other.

Comment: Feel free to assume that I need to collect all distinct Lists because my requirements changed and List needs to be a business object.

Comment: Whether List-Item is one to many or many to many, the problem remains. How to migrate from the two original tables to keep all relations and minimize the number of Lists?

Comment: For simplicity, assume each people won a list 1<->. Create list table with a select from insert if you want. Now populate List_Item with a join People, Item, List. just another insert from select I suppose. To finalize try to find duplicated lists.

Comment: The "to finalize" bit is exactly what my question is about.

Comment: oooookkeeeyyyy, Well my suggestion is: for each List return a row with {ListId, concatenation(items from that listid)}. Not straightforward to do in SQL and that depends on your RDBMS (In MS SQL you ill need a recursive CTE and XML Path for example)

Comment: As the question states, I did exactly that. Is it the only solution? Can it, instead, be done in a few clever joins?

Comment: Maybe you can find a way but I'm afraid that's not possible. btw if you are migrating from a old schema to a new one you ill incur in most integration issues between DB. That said I prefer to create a small program (C#, Java, whatever) to do it. That way I first pump my data to a stag schema, sanitize it, mark rows failed to fit in the new schema, etc. That kind of logic, handling all possible fails, is easier to build in a imperative/procedural program.